# Magento: How to alphabetically sort the state/province dropdown's items

Tags: magento, drop-down-menu, alphabetical-sort

I'd like to alphabetically sort the items in the department/region dropdown. This dropdown is visible on the billing information section on the checkout page.

I am using Magento CE 1.7.0.2 and setting an address in France, hence trying to see France's departments sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution consists in rewriting the script js/varien/forms.js.
In its update function, create a sorted collection of regions, then iterate over this collection and add each region's option.

A better solution, performance wise, is to re-affect region ids in the table directory_country_region. Currently, region's ids order the region by country_id and code. Re-setting the region ids so that regions are ordered by country_id and default_name would do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Billing` block (+ `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping` if you also need to), and in the new class(es), copy and adapt the `getRegionHtmlSelect($type)` method from `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Abstract`.

What you need especially is to sort the result of `$this->getRegionCollection()->toOptionArray()` before using it with `setOptions()`, knowing that it is an array of arrays with `value` and `label` keys.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work. The regions are obtained from the database in Mage_Directory_Helper_Data->getRegionJson() and then fed to the javascript js/varien/forms.js.