# Magento: Sort state/province dropdown alphabetically

Tags: magento-1.7

I've just imported over 4000 country/province codes into the directory_country_region table from here - http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/272591/.  Works great...except for one thing.  The state/provinces are ordered by region_id instead of the default_name column.

It looks like it's already being done at a low level in app/core/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Resource/Region/Collection.php

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('directory/region');

    $this->_countryTable    = $this->getTable('directory/country');
    $this->_regionNameTable = $this->getTable('directory/country_region_name');

    $this->addOrder('name', Varien_Data_Collection::SORT_ORDER_ASC);
    $this->addOrder('default_name', Varien_Data_Collection::SORT_ORDER_ASC);
}
```

I've found several places where this questions was asked but nothing has worked:

[Magento: How to alphabetically sort the state/province dropdown's items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17214309/magento-how-to-alphabetically-sort-the-state-province-dropdowns-items)

I really thought this one would do it but it has no affect:
http://open-source.noads.biz/guide-magento-ecommerce/ordinare-la-tendina-delle-regioni-stati-province.html

Google has failed me and I've run out of ideas.

Answer (score 4):

this modified form.js works as you required

```
VarienForm = Class.create();
VarienForm.prototype = {
    initialize: function(formId, firstFieldFocus){
        this.form       = $(formId);
        if (!this.form) {
            return;
        }
        this.cache      = $A();
        this.currLoader = false;
        this.currDataIndex = false;
        this.validator  = new Validation(this.form);
        this.elementFocus   = this.elementOnFocus.bindAsEventListener(this);
        this.elementBlur    = this.elementOnBlur.bindAsEventListener(this);
        this.childLoader    = this.onChangeChildLoad.bindAsEventListener(this);
        this.highlightClass = 'highlight';
        this.extraChildParams = '';
        this.firstFieldFocus= firstFieldFocus || false;
        this.bindElements();
        if(this.firstFieldFocus){
            try{
                Form.Element.focus(Form.findFirstElement(this.form))
            }
            catch(e){}
        }
    },

    submit : function(url){
        if(this.validator && this.validator.validate()){
             this.form.submit();
        }
        return false;
    },

    bindElements:function (){
        var elements = Form.getElements(this.form);
        for (var row in elements) {
            if (elements[row].id) {
                Event.observe(elements[row],'focus',this.elementFocus);
                Event.observe(elements[row],'blur',this.elementBlur);
            }
        }
    },

    elementOnFocus: function(event){
        var element = Event.findElement(event, 'fieldset');
        if(element){
            Element.addClassName(element, this.highlightClass);
        }
    },

    elementOnBlur: function(event){
        var element = Event.findElement(event, 'fieldset');
        if(element){
            Element.removeClassName(element, this.highlightClass);
        }
    },

    setElementsRelation: function(parent, child, dataUrl, first){
        if (parent=$(parent)) {
            // TODO: array of relation and caching
            if (!this.cache[parent.id]){
                this.cache[parent.id] = $A();
                this.cache[parent.id]['child']     = child;
                this.cache[parent.id]['dataUrl']   = dataUrl;
                this.cache[parent.id]['data']      = $A();
                this.cache[parent.id]['first']      = first || false;
            }
            Event.observe(parent,'change',this.childLoader);
        }
    },

    onChangeChildLoad: function(event){
        element = Event.element(event);
        this.elementChildLoad(element);
    },

    elementChildLoad: function(element, callback){
        this.callback = callback || false;
        if (element.value) {
            this.currLoader = element.id;
            this.currDataIndex = element.value;
            if (this.cache[element.id]['data'][element.value]) {
                this.setDataToChild(this.cache[element.id]['data'][element.value]);
            }
            else{
                new Ajax.Request(this.cache[this.currLoader]['dataUrl'],{
                        method: 'post',
                        parameters: {"parent":element.value},
                        onComplete: this.reloadChildren.bind(this)
                });
            }
        }
    },

    reloadChildren: function(transport){
        var data = eval('(' + transport.responseText + ')');
        this.cache[this.currLoader]['data'][this.currDataIndex] = data;
        this.setDataToChild(data);
    },

    setDataToChild: function(data){
        if (data.length) {
            var child = $(this.cache[this.currLoader]['child']);
            if (child){
                var html = '<select name="'+child.name+'" id="'+child.id+'" class="'+child.className+'" title="'+child.title+'" '+this.extraChildParams+'>';
                if(this.cache[this.currLoader]['first']){
                    html+= '<option value="">'+this.cache[this.currLoader]['first']+'</option>';
                }
                for (var i in data){
                    if(data[i].value) {
                        html+= '<option value="'+data[i].value+'"';
                        if(child.value && (child.value == data[i].value || child.value == data[i].label)){
                            html+= ' selected';
                        }
                        html+='>'+data[i].label+'</option>';
                    }
                }
                html+= '</select>';
                Element.insert(child, {before: html});
                Element.remove(child);
            }
        }
        else{
            var child = $(this.cache[this.currLoader]['child']);
            if (child){
                var html = '<input type="text" name="'+child.name+'" id="'+child.id+'" class="'+child.className+'" title="'+child.title+'" '+this.extraChildParams+'>';
                Element.insert(child, {before: html});
                Element.remove(child);
            }
        }

        this.bindElements();
        if (this.callback) {
            this.callback();
        }
    }
}

RegionUpdater = Class.create();
RegionUpdater.prototype = {
    initialize: function (countryEl, regionTextEl, regionSelectEl, regions, disableAction, zipEl)
    {
        this.countryEl = $(countryEl);
        this.regionTextEl = $(regionTextEl);
        this.regionSelectEl = $(regionSelectEl);
        this.zipEl = $(zipEl);
        this.config = regions['config'];
        delete regions.config;
        this.regions = regions;

        this.disableAction = (typeof disableAction=='undefined') ? 'hide' : disableAction;
        this.zipOptions = (typeof zipOptions=='undefined') ? false : zipOptions;

        if (this.regionSelectEl.options.length<=1) {
            this.update();
        }

        Event.observe(this.countryEl, 'change', this.update.bind(this));
    },

    _checkRegionRequired: function()
    {
        var label, wildCard;
        var elements = [this.regionTextEl, this.regionSelectEl];
        var that = this;
        if (typeof this.config == 'undefined') {
            return;
        }
        var regionRequired = this.config.regions_required.indexOf(this.countryEl.value) >= 0;

        elements.each(function(currentElement) {
            Validation.reset(currentElement);
            label = $$('label[for="' + currentElement.id + '"]')[0];
            if (label) {
                wildCard = label.down('em') || label.down('span.required');
                if (!that.config.show_all_regions) {
                    if (regionRequired) {
                        label.up().show();
                    } else {
                        label.up().hide();
                    }
                }
            }

            if (label && wildCard) {
                if (!regionRequired) {
                    wildCard.hide();
                    if (label.hasClassName('required')) {
                        label.removeClassName('required');
                    }
                } else if (regionRequired) {
                    wildCard.show();
                    if (!label.hasClassName('required')) {
                        label.addClassName('required')
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!regionRequired) {
                if (currentElement.hasClassName('required-entry')) {
                    currentElement.removeClassName('required-entry');
                }
                if ('select' == currentElement.tagName.toLowerCase() &&
                    currentElement.hasClassName('validate-select')) {
                    currentElement.removeClassName('validate-select');
                }
            } else {
                if (!currentElement.hasClassName('required-entry')) {
                    currentElement.addClassName('required-entry');
                }
                if ('select' == currentElement.tagName.toLowerCase() &&
                    !currentElement.hasClassName('validate-select')) {
                    currentElement.addClassName('validate-select');
                }
            }
        });
    },

    update: function()
    {
        if (this.regions[this.countryEl.value]) {
            var i, option, region, def;

            def = this.regionSelectEl.getAttribute('defaultValue');
            if (this.regionTextEl) {
                if (!def) {
                    def = this.regionTextEl.value.toLowerCase();
                }
                this.regionTextEl.value = '';
            }

            this.regionSelectEl.options.length = 1;
            for (regionId in this.regions[this.countryEl.value]) {
                region = this.regions[this.countryEl.value][regionId];

                option = document.createElement('OPTION');
                option.value = regionId;
                option.text = region.name.stripTags();
                option.title = region.name;

                if (this.regionSelectEl.options.add) {
                    this.regionSelectEl.options.add(option);
                } else {
                    this.regionSelectEl.appendChild(option);
                }
                if (this.regionSelectEl.length) {
                    var i = 0 ;
                    while( i< this.regionSelectEl.length) {
                    option_i = this.regionSelectEl.options[i] ;
                    if (option_i.value !="" && option_i.text > option.text) break;
                    else i++ ;
                    }
                if (this.regionSelectEl.options.add) { //IE
                    this.regionSelectEl.options.add(option, i);
                    } else {
                    this.regionSelectEl.add(option, option_i);
                    } 

                    }
                    else
                    {

                    if (this.regionSelectEl.options.add) { //IE
                    this.regionSelectEl.options.add(option);
                    } else {
                    this.regionSelectEl.options.add(option, null);
                    //this.regionSelectEl.appendChild(option);
                    }
                    }

                if (regionId==def || (region.name && region.name.toLowerCase()==def) ||
                    (region.name && region.code.toLowerCase()==def)
                ) {
                    this.regionSelectEl.value = regionId;
                }
            }

            if (this.disableAction=='hide') {
                if (this.regionTextEl) {
                    this.regionTextEl.style.display = 'none';
                }

                this.regionSelectEl.style.display = '';
            } else if (this.disableAction=='disable') {
                if (this.regionTextEl) {
                    this.regionTextEl.disabled = true;
                }
                this.regionSelectEl.disabled = false;
            }
            this.setMarkDisplay(this.regionSelectEl, true);
            jQuery(this.regionSelectEl).selectbox();
        } else {
            if (this.disableAction=='hide') {
                if (this.regionTextEl) {
                    this.regionTextEl.style.display = '';
                }
                this.regionSelectEl.style.display = 'none';
                Validation.reset(this.regionSelectEl);
            } else if (this.disableAction=='disable') {
                if (this.regionTextEl) {
                    this.regionTextEl.disabled = false;
                }
                this.regionSelectEl.disabled = true;
            } else if (this.disableAction=='nullify') {
                this.regionSelectEl.options.length = 1;
                this.regionSelectEl.value = '';
                this.regionSelectEl.selectedIndex = 0;
                this.lastCountryId = '';
            }
            this.setMarkDisplay(this.regionSelectEl, false);
        }

        this._checkRegionRequired();
        // Make Zip and its label required/optional
        var zipUpdater = new ZipUpdater(this.countryEl.value, this.zipEl);
        zipUpdater.update();
    },

    setMarkDisplay: function(elem, display){
        elem = $(elem);
        var labelElement = elem.up(0).down('label > span.required') ||
                           elem.up(1).down('label > span.required') ||
                           elem.up(0).down('label.required > em') ||
                           elem.up(1).down('label.required > em');
        if(labelElement) {
            inputElement = labelElement.up().next('input');
            if (display) {
                labelElement.show();
                if (inputElement) {
                    inputElement.addClassName('required-entry');
                }
            } else {
                labelElement.hide();
                if (inputElement) {
                    inputElement.removeClassName('required-entry');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

ZipUpdater = Class.create();
ZipUpdater.prototype = {
    initialize: function(country, zipElement)
    {
        this.country = country;
        this.zipElement = $(zipElement);
    },

    update: function()
    {
        // Country ISO 2-letter codes must be pre-defined
        if (typeof optionalZipCountries == 'undefined') {
            return false;
        }

        // Ajax-request and normal content load compatibility
        if (this.zipElement != undefined) {
            this._setPostcodeOptional();
        } else {
            Event.observe(window, "load", this._setPostcodeOptional.bind(this));
        }
    },

    _setPostcodeOptional: function()
    {
        this.zipElement = $(this.zipElement);
        if (this.zipElement == undefined) {
            return false;
        }

        // find label
        var label = $$('label[for="' + this.zipElement.id + '"]')[0];
        if (label != undefined) {
            var wildCard = label.down('em') || label.down('span.required');
        }

        // Make Zip and its label required/optional
        if (optionalZipCountries.indexOf(this.country) != -1) {
            while (this.zipElement.hasClassName('required-entry')) {
                this.zipElement.removeClassName('required-entry');
            }
            if (wildCard != undefined) {
                wildCard.hide();
            }
        } else {
            this.zipElement.addClassName('required-entry');
            if (wildCard != undefined) {
                wildCard.show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could improve your answer by summarizing the modifications you made to form.js.

Comment: Hi,in RegionUpdater class, the update method was modified to reorder the json data by text. In the original method it was ordered by value.

Comment: If you want it also in admin, you have to apply same mod to js/mage/adminhtml/form.js

Answer (score 0):

Looks like not a collection problem.
If you check your returned json in frontend you can notice that elements are sorted.

The problem is in RegionUpdater (varien/js.js) class that parses elements like integers so your order is not followed.

An ugly solution is to convert id as strings in Mage_Directory_Helper_Data

```
foreach ($collection as $region)
{
      if (!$region->getRegionId()) 
      {
              continue;
      }
      $regions[$region->getCountryId()]["'".$region->getRegionId()."'"] = array('code' => $region->getCode(),'name' => $this->__($region->getName()));
}
$json = Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($regions);
```

in this way your ids are strings so parser follow the array order but now you have to remove quotes in frontend in varien/js.js in update:function of RegionUpdater class:

```
option.value = regionId.replace(/'/g, '');
```

I know it's ugly but it's fast , otherwise you should recode whole "select region" render